# Object record in particular application

Tags: custom-object, record

I have problem view record object difference in two application using general object.

**Example** :

- I have created my object name "Company" and two application.
- Object Company have 3 field (Name, TotalEmployees, Address ).
- Application1 and Application2 using object "Company".
- I want user only view record "Company" create by particular Application

How i can resolve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't differentiate object records based on application. Here is what you can try:

Assuming the set of users for both applications are different:

- Create two record types for the object
- Assign first record type to the profiles of users using first application and similarly do it for second application.
- A profile should have only record type for this object.

If the users for both applications are same, we don't need to restrict anything.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. 
When i using record type apply for application so old application will view record created by new application1 or application2.
Example : Old applicaiton using object company and i create new two app with same object.